# cannot compile and works the getColumnSearchProps and table Reset filters and sorters dont work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to load my `Exposures` page, but I'm getting this **error**:

> ./src/Exposures.js   Line 58:9:   'state'                is not
> defined  no-undef   Line 63:9:   'getColumnSearchProps' is not defined
> no-undef
> handleSearch1          is not defined  no-undef
> handleReset1           is not defined  no-undef Failed to compile.

I'm trying to implement a column search filter `handleSearch1` and search filter reset `handleReset1`, but it's not working.
[image: My Result]

Here is the Exposures code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import Highlighter from 'react-highlight-words';
import {EditOutlined, StockOutlined,SearchOutlined  } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Table, PageHeader, Button, message,Input, Space } from 'antd';
import Axios from 'axios';
import moment from 'moment';

const Exposures = () => {
        
        const dataSource = [
          {
            id: '1',
            pwner: 'Mike',
            asOfDate: '2015/01/01',
            description: '22  Street',
          },
          {
            key: '2',
            name: 'John',
            asOfDate: '2015/06/01',
            description: '10 Downing Street',
          },
          {
            key: '3',
            name: 'paton',
            asOfDate: '2015/03/01',
            description: '234  Street',
          },
          {
            key: '4',
            name: 'molug',
            asOfDate: '2015/04/01',
            description: '1345  Street',
          },
        ];
        
        
        //start code to handle search
        state = {
            searchText: '',
            searchedColumn: '',
        };

   
         getColumnSearchProps = dataIndex => ({
            filterDropdown: ({ setSelectedKeys, selectedKeys, confirm, clearFilters }) => (
            <div style={{ padding: 8 }}>
                <Input
                ref={node => {
                    this.searchInput = node;
                }}
                placeholder={`Search ${dataIndex}`}
                value={selectedKeys[0]}
                onChange={e => setSelectedKeys(e.target.value ? [e.target.value] : [])}
                onPressEnter={() => this.handleSearch1(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
                style={{ width: 188, marginBottom: 8, display: 'block' }}
                />
                <Space>
                <Button
                    type="primary"
                    onClick={() => this.handleSearch1(selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex)}
                    icon={<SearchOutlined />}
                    size="small"
                    style={{ width: 90 }}
                >
                    Search
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={() => this.handleReset1(clearFilters)} size="small" style={{ width: 90 }}>
                    Reset
                </Button>
                </Space>
            </div>
            ),
            filterIcon: filtered => <SearchOutlined style={{ color: filtered ? '#1890ff' : undefined }} />,
            onFilter: (value, record) =>
            record[dataIndex] ? record[dataIndex].toString().toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()) : '',
            onFilterDropdownVisibleChange: visible => {
            if (visible) {
                setTimeout(() => this.searchInput.select());
            }
            },
            render: text =>
            this.state.searchedColumn === dataIndex ? (
                <Highlighter
                highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
                searchWords={[this.state.searchText]}
                autoEscape
                textToHighlight={text ? text.toString() : ''}
                />
            ) : (
                text
            ),
        });

        handleSearch1 = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
            confirm();
            this.setState({
            searchText: selectedKeys[0],
            searchedColumn: dataIndex,
            });
        };

        handleReset1 = clearFilters => {
            clearFilters();
            this.setState({ searchText: '' });
        };
        
        //end code to handle search
  
    const columnDefinitions = [
        {
            title: 'Id',
            dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
            title: 'Owner',
            dataIndex: 'owner'
        },
        {
            title: 'AsOfDate',
            dataIndex: 'asOfDate',
            width: 15,
            render:(asOfDate)=>moment(asOfDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        },
        {
            title: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
            width: 80,
            ...this.getColumnSearchProps('description') // not working
        }
    ];


    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <PageHeader
                title={<span><StockOutlined /> <span>Historical Management</span></span>} 
            ></PageHeader>
            <Table
                size="middle"
                rowKey="id"
                bordered
                dataSource={dataSource}
                columns={columnDefinitions}
                pagination={{ pageSizeOptions: ['10', '20', '30'] }}
                loading={loading}
                scroll={{ x: 3000 }}
            />
    
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default Exposures;
```

Here below is my `apps.js` file where i called the `Exposures.js` file in a `Route`:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Exposures from './Exposures';
import { Layout, Menu, Col, Row, Typography } from 'antd';
import { Link, Switch, useLocation, Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.less';
import Logo from './RGB.png';


const { Text } = Typography;

const { Header, Content, Footer } = Layout;

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;

const menuKeys =
{
    model: "definitions",
 
}


function App() {
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState();
    const location = useLocation();
    

    return (
            <Layout style={{ minHeight: "100%" }}>
                <Header className="header">
                    <Row justify="space-between">
                        <Col>
                            <Menu
                                selectedKeys={menuKeys[location.pathname.substring(1)]} theme="dark"  mode="horizontal">
                                <Menu.Item>
                                    <img alt="logo" src={Logo} style={{ "height": "61px" }} />
                                    <MenuItem  key="Exposures">
                                        <StockOutlined /><Link to="/exposurepage">page Exposures</Link>
                                    </MenuItem >
                                </SubMenu>
                            </Menu>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Header>
                <Content style={{ padding: '0 50px' }}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/exposurepage" ><Exposures /></Route>
                    </Switch>

                </Content>
                <Footer style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>©2020</Footer>
            </Layout>
        );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please, update this post adding your current problems. What you're facing now is implementation problem — you must update the state change methods to match your hook state

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO :)

It seems you're trying to implement a state inside your functional component.
Since it's a functional component, it's different from the class state implementation, because you'll need to use a hook, like this:

```
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
const [searchedColumn, setSearchedColumn] = useState('');
```

It's important to remember:
The first value, for example, searchText, returns the state value. The second value, setSearchText, it's equivalent to this.setState(), but it only handles the searchText value :)

Implementing it correctly will remove the state error.

Now, to remove the `handleReset1` error and `getColumnSearchProps` (errors regarding function declaration), you must declare these functions as const, like this:

```
const handleSearch1 = (selectedKeys, confirm, dataIndex) => {
            confirm();
            this.setState({
            searchText: selectedKeys[0],
            searchedColumn: dataIndex,
            });
        };

const handleReset1 = clearFilters => {
            clearFilters();
            this.setState({ searchText: '' });
        };
```

It works this way because it's a functional component, so your functions in these components must be declared as a variable.

After that, you'll get some new errors regarding the use of this inside a functional component, so you'll need just to avoid it (and also update your setState calls to match the hooks).

Check out the useState hook documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
And components documentation https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Happy coding! :D